# How to count the no. of columns in dynamic grid view before binding the data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dynamic grid view in which two types of data is showing.
in first case it is showing 4 column grid and in second case it is showing 6 column grid.

I want to count the no of automatically generated though sql query.

Please help.

```
con.Open();
GridView3.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (GridView3.Columns.Count < 5)
{
 GridView1.DataBind();
}
else
{
GridView2.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

**But it is always showing no. of columns are 0 at "GridView3.Columns.Count" instead of 4 or 6.**

Comment: Please show some work or what you have got so far, it is far easier to assist if we can see what it is you are trying to do, rather than just trying to figure it out from your explanation.

Comment: `dataTable.Columns.Count` Assuming DataTable is your datasource.